# How can I add a second nic in Test Kitchen with the ec2 driver?

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

Looking at the readme I see lots of options for adding extra storage but nothing for a second nic. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at this time. This would usually only matter for multi-server or cluster testing in general which is something we don't currently support very well (or really, at all). You could try using [Kitchen-Terraform](https://newcontext-oss.github.io/kitchen-terraform) to work around this.

Comment: I use terraform so this is nice to know. So define the second nice in the Terraform plan? I need a second nic on an instance due to a strange docker configuration that requires it.

Comment: You would have to switch drivers entirely, and kitchen-terraform is not a drop in replacement